# Java-Gradle-Project compiles only once, then throws "cannot find class" error

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, build

I recently wanted to learn more about Gradle. So I created a new Gradle Project (Im using IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.2), which imports Java as an external Library. After that, I created a simple class called "Main" in the "java"-src-folder, which simply prints out "Hello World!", when the included main method is called. I didn't change anything in the build.gradle-file.

And here's the issue: When I run the main method for the first time, everything works completely fine, as it should. But when I try to run the main method again, without changing anything, I get two errors:

1.) Could not find or load main class Main
2.) Process command "/*path to jdk*/bin/java.exe" finished with non-zero exit value 1

But every time I change something in the build.gradle-file, I can run the main method again, one more time, but then throws those two errors again, when I want to run it again, without changing anything.

I already tried to fix these errors, by adding 'mainClassName' into the build.gradle-file, editing the run-configurations, reinstalled IntelliJ and Gradle, tried with other JDKs, but nothing worked.

I would be really thankful if somebody could help me out with these issues because, with them, I am not able to use Gradle (in IntelliJ) for my Java Projects.

### [image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: You don't appear to have the `application` plugin applied, so I assume you are not running the application via Gradle. That may be the cause of your problem. Check out [The Application Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html#header) documentation. Then either run `./gradlew run` from the command line or have IntelliJ delegate to that task via a run configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this does not work either. But I don't actually think, that the Application-Plugin is part of the problem, because everyone else I asked, was able to run their programs without any problems, and without applying the application plugin.

Comment: Well, one reason to use a build tool is to make your build IDE/editor independent. Your IDE should both configure itself based on the build tool configuration, and delegate build tasks to the build tool. Otherwise you risk having different configurations in your IDE and your build tool (meaning some things may work with one but not the other). A common way to execute a Gradle project is via the `run` task added by the `application` plugin. Though maybe something has changed that I'm not aware of.

Comment: But all that being said, it looks like the `Main.class` file is being deleted somehow. If you look in your first image there's a `build/classes/java/main/Main.class` file present. But in your second image that file seems to be gone and there's just the `build/classes/java` directory. I can't tell why that's happening based on the given information, but hopefully it might help you search in the right direction.

Comment: Yeah, I already realised that. I tried to copy the .class-file before running the code for the second time, and then paste it again, but that didn't work (to be honest: I didn't expect it to work ;) ). But anyways: Thank you for trying to solve this problem :)

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you run application from command line outside IDE?

Comment: Yes, I do, and it doesn't matter if I use the CMD, or Windows PowerShell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Gradle works now. But I really don't know why. I didn't change nothing (really: Nothing). But still: Thanks everyone for trying to solve this problem :)